# FLOSS SVG animation / video editing software with both WYSIWYG and XML editor

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, animation, svg

I am looking for a software package for **SVG animation** or a **video editor** to create animations/videos that is:

**1.** Free Libre Open Source Software (FLOSS)

**2.** runs on GNU/Linux

**3.** allows me to use a SVG file as watermark

**4.** is organized in layers (like Inkscape or GIMP), but for video rather than static images

**5.** allows me to move SVG elements both with its WYSIWYG interface and with an internal XML editor (like Inkscape)

**6.** allows me to define X and Y position and size of an SVG object (like in the Inkscape UI), but also at different time-frames: i.e.: by knowing position and size at the starting frame (let's say 1) and the ending frame (let's say 60) creates the intermediate frames automatically (2, 3, ..., 59) and gives the illusion of motion (it makes me think of very early versions of Flash)

**7.** allows me to access the different frames with a scroll/progress bar

Thanks in advance!