# Software to create animated SVG with movement along path

Tags: animation, svg

In the days of Flash in the Macromedia Flash editor it was possible to create animations in .swf or .gif. And it was possible to draw a line and set an animation of an object moving along this line. I know that SVG should also support animation along a path. I can make such animation by coding it in SVG tags. But I have a task to make a lot of such animations. And I would like to have a similar tool to create them. I want the same thing as the old Macromedia Flash but made for this new format. Not just frame-by-frame animation but real vector animation using proper SVG tags like the `<animateMotion>` tag.

Comment: Are you looking for animation with JavaScript, SMIL, or CSS?

Comment: @Kodiologist, SMIL/CSS. Well, as long as it's suited for creating interactive experiences in modern browsers anything will do. But it should be something efficient.

Comment: As far as I know there are currently no GUI applications capable of animating SVGs https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32370/floss-svg-animation-video-editing-software-with-both-wysiwyg-and-xml-editor

Comment: Isn't it just very sad?